# Query a list of Project numbers from a table of Projects via CRM Custom Plugin

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I have a table of project entities in CRM, each project entity has a text field called "project number".  I want to query out a list of all the project numbers available in the table.

All of the sources that I have looked at, mention that I need to use a `ServiceContext` or `XrmServiceContext()`but it seems that those are generated using the **CrmSvcUtil** tool.  The tutorial I used for this portion is found [here](http://mscrmshop.blogspot.com/2012/03/how-to-use-crmsvcutil-code-generation.html).

From my past experience with CRM Plugin development, [I have found that I am not allowed to do any local tasks within the plugin execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55171488/creating-dynamics-crm-plugin-to-execute-external-task), therefore using the **CrmSvcUtil** tool conflicts with this.

Am I approaching this situation all wrong? I have access to `OrganizationServiceContext` but I am not sure if this will give me access to query my project entities.

EDIT:
My references listed below but LocalPluginContext cannot be found.  Quick google search suggested I just add the items from the sdk but I have added everything.
[image]

Comment: Are you just wanting to manually query the data, or do you want to run some code on against it?  If it's code, what is triggering it, and what should it do with the information?

Comment: @Daryl I want my plugin to trigger on Entity Create (Entity is a Project), and the Pipeline Stage of Execution is PreOperation.  My end goal of this plugin is to automatically assign the newly created Project Entity a project number.  The project number generator function will use the queried list will be used as a input to generate project number.  The project number will consist of letters and the field type is "Line of Text".

Comment: LocalPluginContext is an example context listed in the docs, but not compiled anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 Ways you could achieve This.
1. Console Applicaiton where you do not need context rather you sign in and then get IOrganizationService

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IOrganizationService organizationService = null;    
            try
            {
                ClientCredentials clientCredentials = new ClientCredentials();
                clientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "AdminCRM@dabc.onmicrosoft.com";
                clientCredentials.UserName.Password = "pwd";

                //For Dynamics 365 Customer Engagement V9.X, set Security Protocol as TLS12
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                //Get the URL from CRM, Navigate to Settings -> Customizations -> Developer Resources
                //Copy and Paste Organization Service Endpoint Address URL

                organizationService = (IOrganizationService)new OrganizationServiceProxy(new Uri("https:/[OrgUrl]/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc"),
                    null, clientCredentials, null);

                if (organizationService != null)
                {
                    Guid userid = ((WhoAmIResponse)organizationService.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest())).UserId;

                    if (userid != Guid.Empty)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Connection Established Successfully...");                          
                    FetchXmlTestQuery(organizationService);
                    queryExpressionTest(organizationService);    

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed to Established Connection!!!");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception caught - " + ex.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();    

        }

 private static void queryExpressionTest(IOrganizationService organizationService)
        {
            QueryExpression qe = new QueryExpression();
            qe.EntityName = "account";
            qe.ColumnSet= new ColumnSet("name", "accountnumber");

            EntityCollection coll = organizationService.RetrieveMultiple(qe);
            foreach (Entity acunt in coll.Entities)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name of Account: " + acunt.GetAttributeValue<string>("name"));
                Console.WriteLine("Number of Account: " + acunt.GetAttributeValue<string>("accountnumber"));
            }

        }


private static void FetchXmlTestQuery(IOrganizationService CrmConn)
        {
            // Retrieve all accounts owned by the user with read access rights to the accounts and   
            // where the last name of the user is not Cannon.   
            string fetch = @"  
   <fetch>
  <entity name='account' >
    <attribute name='name' />
<attribute name='accountnumber' />
    <link-entity name='contact' from='parentcustomerid' to='accountid' link-type='inner' alias='Contact' >
      <attribute name='fullname' alias = 'Contact.Fullname' />
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch> ";

           EntityCollection Coll = CrmConn.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetch));

                foreach (Entity acunt in Coll.Entities)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Name of Account: " + acunt.GetAttributeValue<string>("name"));
                    Console.WriteLine("Name of Contact: "  + acunt.GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>("Contact.Fullname").Value);
                    Console.WriteLine("Number of Account: " + acunt.GetAttributeValue<string>("accountnumber"));
            }


        }
```

Now you could also use Plugin Context

```
protected override void ExecuteCrmPlugin(LocalPluginContext localContext)
        {
            if (localContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("localContext");
            }

            // TODO: Implement your custom plug-in business logic.
            IPluginExecutionContext context = localContext.PluginExecutionContext;
            ITracingService tracingService = localContext.TracingService;
            IOrganizationService orgService = localContext.OrganizationService;

            FetchXmlTestQuery(orgService);
            queryExpressionTest(orgService);
}

 private void FetchXmlTestQuery(IOrganizationService orgService)
        {
            // Retrieve all accounts owned by the user with read access rights to the accounts and   
            // where the last name of the user is not Cannon.   
            string fetch = @"  
   <fetch>
  <entity name='account' >
    <attribute name='name' />
<attribute name='accountnumber' />
    <link-entity name='contact' from='parentcustomerid' to='accountid' link-type='inner' alias='Contact' >
      <attribute name='fullname' alias = 'Contact.Fullname' />
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch> ";

            EntityCollection Coll = orgService.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetch));

            foreach (Entity acunt in Coll.Entities)
            {
              string accountname= acunt.GetAttributeValue<string>("name");
             string accountnr=  acunt.GetAttributeValue<string>("accountnumber");
            }
        }
        private static void queryExpressionTest(IOrganizationService organizationService)
        {
            QueryExpression qe = new QueryExpression();
            qe.EntityName = "account";
            qe.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("name", "accountnumber");

            EntityCollection coll = organizationService.RetrieveMultiple(qe);
            foreach (Entity acunt in coll.Entities)
            {
                string accountname = acunt.GetAttributeValue<string>("name");
                string accountnr =  acunt.GetAttributeValue<string>("accountnumber");
            }

        }
```

Comment: would ExecuteCrmPlugin replace the Execute function that is usually associated with Plugins?  If not, how would I get LocalPluginContext localContext?

Comment: Never mind.  Fairly simple. var localContext = new LocalPluginContext(serviceProvider);

Comment: Glad that helped!! It would be nice if you mark this as solved would help others as well.

Comment: Almost there, would you happen to know where library LocalPluginContext is associated with?  I am receiving a "The type or namespace name 'LocalPluginContext' could not be found"  error.  I will attach a image of all of my references above which were pull from my sdk/bin directory.

Comment: I use Dynamics 365 developer toolkit for visual studio. Here is one link with example: http://dynamicslmp.com/2017/12/07/dynamics-365-plugin-development/ and here is how you install it: https://community.dynamics.com/365/b/dynamics365fordevelopers/archive/2017/03/07/install-dynamics-365-developer-toolkit-with-visual-studio-2017

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I did not use that last suggestion by going through the development tool kit but I was able to create IPluginExecutionContext, IOrganizationServiceFactory, IOrganizationService using IServiceProvider.  That being said I used the suggested XMLFetch method and was successfully able to return my list!

Answer (score 1):

Inside the plugin you will get the whole execution context of the pipeline & Organization Service access to extend the business functionality in the same pipeline.

These below code snippets are the boiler plate code will give you the various necessary parts like tracing service for logging, context to get target entity, images, etc and `IOrganizationService`to make service calls like Update, Retrieve, etc achieve the platform extension.

As you know there will be a single public class in Plugin & a single public method `Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)` and we will get everything using this single parameter **serviceProvider**

```
// Obtain the tracing service
ITracingService tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));

// Obtain the execution context from the service provider.  
IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

// Obtain the organization service reference which you will need for  
// web service calls.  
IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
```

When you want to query for other project numbers from the database, use the `service.RetrieveMultiple` method to query. You can pass the fetchxml query or use queryexpression to do it.

You can find lot of examples online. [Starter example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/use-fetchxml-construct-query#using-organization-service).

Comment: Thanks again Arun for pointing me towards fetchxml queries.  Can't believe I overlooked this, makes it much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would recommend.

1. Install [XrmToolBox](https://www.XrmToolBox.com) (make sure you unblock the zip file before unzipping it)
2. Install the Early Bound Generator and the Visual Studio Solution Accelerator from the XrmToolBox plugin store within the tool.
3. Run the Visual Studio Solution Accelerator either adding the core projects to your existing solution, or using it to create a new solution.  I'd suggest adding the example plugins so you can see how to create a plugin.  Also suggest using EarlyBinding.
4. Run the EarlyBoundGenerator, pasting in the path that was copied to your clipboard from the Visual Studio Solution Accelerator.  Add whatever custom entities you'll need for your plugin.  Create All.
5. Create your plugin in the plugin project.